# Android timer throws Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, timer, nullpointerexception

I've made a game in Android and got pretty much everything to work, except the timer. It's throwing a NPE whenever I try to run the game. I've tried a few different timers, looked through loads of pages trying to find an answer but have had no luck so far. I've posted the relevant code and logcat below.

```
public class GameView extends View {

    private Paint redPaint, blackPaint;
    private Bitmap ball1;
    private String output = "Output will appear here";
    private int ballX, ballY;
    private int radius = 50;
    private int count = 0;

    private int circleX = 350;
    private int circleY = 550;

     TextView tv;

        public GameView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            redPaint = new Paint();
            redPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
            blackPaint = new Paint();
            blackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            ball1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

            new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    tv.setText("done!");
                }
            }.start();

        }
```

Logcat, the error is at `tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);`

```
05-11 20:11:59.244      645-645/com.example.jeff.ballgame E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.jeff.ballgame.GameView$1.onTick(GameView.java:39)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-11 20:11:59.374      645-651/com.example.jeff.ballgame I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-11 20:11:59.394      645-651/com.example.jeff.ballgame I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-11 20:11:59.774      645-651/com.example.jeff.ballgame I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-11 20:11:59.784      645-651/com.example.jeff.ballgame I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-11 20:16:59.628      645-645/com.example.jeff.ballgame I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 645 SIG: 9
```

GameActivity code

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    GameView GV;
    TextView tv;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        GV = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(GV);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);


        new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tv.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            }
            public void onFinish() {
                tv.setText("done!");
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

Comment: What class is extending GameView?

Comment: It's being extended in GameActivity, tried to do the timer in that class but it wouldn't draw over the GameView.

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    GameView GV;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        GV = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(GV);

    }

Comment: is GameView extending View?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the original question to include the top section of code.

Comment: Check that your textview isn't null there. I believe it is.

Comment: tv is null, because class extending View, can't have children

Comment: your view is not inflated at this point. findViewById will always return null. create your timer and look for your textview in onFinishInflate

Comment: I've never used onFinishInflate, relatively new to Android, what would I do with that?

Answer (score 1):

The textView is null.

```
tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

will always return null because is called before `setContentView()` that i think you call in `onCreate()`

Comment: Thanks, how would I solve this? I tried putting the timer and TextView in the GameActivity after setContentView but it still threw the error. I'll update the original to include the GameActivity code.

Comment: You call setcontentView() twice, The second time will override all the content inflated in your layout so the tv is null again